# unreadable zsh shell and backspace not work on zsh shell on Docker

Tags: linux, docker, zsh, boot2docker

I used the `FROM rails:onbuild` image

- You can see the wrong/unreadable encoding here
  [image]
- When I type backspace after **test**, it didn't work, it appended spaces on the shell

[image]

Here's the environment variables ,

any ideas for the bug ?

```
RUBY_MAJOR=2.2
RUBY_VERSION=2.2.2
RUBY_DOWNLOAD_SHA256=5ffc0f317e429e6b29d4a98ac521c3ce65481bfd22a8cf845fa02a7b113d9b44
GEM_HOME=/usr/local/bundle
BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=/usr/local/bundle
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
SHLVL=1
PWD=/associate-app
OLDPWD=/associate-app
ZSH=/root/.oh-my-zsh
PAGER=less
LESS=-R
LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
_=/usr/bin/env
```

### DOCEKRFILE   (here's my docker file)

```
FROM rails:onbuild
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y -qq --force-yes install \
        build-essential \
        tree \
        locales \
        ruby-dev \
        vim \
        vim-scripts \
        git \
        git-flow\
        curl \
        zsh \
        sudo



# Install Zsh
RUN git clone git://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git ~/.oh-my-zsh \
      && cp ~/.oh-my-zsh/templates/zshrc.zsh-template ~/.zshrc \
      && chsh -s /bin/zsh

RUN sed -i -E "s/^plugins=\((.*)\)$/plugins=(\1 git git-flow ruby tmux)/" ~/.zshrc


# Make ssh dir
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
# Copy over private key, and set permissions
ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
# Create known_hosts
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
# Add bitbuckets key
RUN ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts


RUN echo "alias ls='ls --color=auto'" >> /etc/zsh/zshrc && \
    echo "alias ll='ls -halF'" >> /etc/zsh/zshrc && \
    echo "alias ls='ls --color=auto'" >> /etc/profile && \
    echo "alias ll='ls -halF'" >> /etc/zsh/zshrc

# copy GEMFILE
WORKDIR /tmp
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

RUN mkdir /associate-app
WORKDIR /associate-app
ADD . /associate-app

RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en  
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8  
CMD echo 'LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8' >> ~/.zshrc && \
    echo 'LANG=C.UTF-8' >> ~/.zshrc && \
    echo 'LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8' >> ~/.zshrc && \
CMD ["zsh"]
```

#### stty -a

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 164; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

Answer (score 3):

Your local settings are inconsistent

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

That is, `LANGUAGE` is not using UTF-8, while the other settings are doing this.

That may be part of the problem.

Also, some terminals implement the `iutf8` setting for `stty`.  That tells the terminal driver how to adjust the cursor position for multibyte (UTF-8) characters.  You might check to see if `stty -a` shows `-iutf8` (feature disabled), and enable it if it is not, e.g.,

```
stty -a
stty iutf8
```

When the feature is available, the terminal driver knows that it should take into account whether the text uses UTF-8 (and may have multiple bytes per column).  If it does not, it will count each byte as a column, and when erasing the "last" character, may do something like this:

```
backspace space space
```

producing the effect which is shown above.

Finally, it would be nice to know the actual *terminal* in use.  For instance, rxvt does not support UTF-8; xterm can be configured with/without UTF-8. The value for `TERM` is largely irrelevant, since your shell is likely ignoring it in favor of built-in behavior.

Comment: can you post `echo $TERM` when you enter your container with `docker exec -it my_container bash`?